# Rails app on Windows 10 with WLS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-10

```
Windows 10
WLS
Rails 5.1
MySQL
```

I installed the Windows Linux Services on my Windows 10 machine.

I have Apache2 and MySQL server installed natively on the Windows 10 machine, and they work fine. I am also running a Rails development environment inside the Bash Shell, and everything works OK (bundle, rake, etc), except for migrations, where I get the error message:

Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

I tried running

```
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev --assume-yes
```

inside the Bash Shell, but I am getting a message telling that both MySQL server and client are installed and running.

Has anyone run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WSL you have to start the mysql service in order to connect to the database by typing

```
sudo service mysql start
```

in bash.

Comment: In my post, I mentioned that I'm already running the Mysql server, and that when I tried to re-install it in WSL, it told me that the server is running and it's the latest version